# capturing logging messages from imported python file

Tags: python, logging

Getting logging information from an imported python file.

I am building a python based test suite. 
The tests are called using __import function
I would like to capture the logging messages (in tests) in my test application. The logging messages are generated by using the python logging module.
How can I do that ? For example in psuedo code:

```
    for test in testList:  

               # do something
             # Import Test   

             testid = __import__(test)  

             testOut = testid.run(parameter1,parameter2)    

             print "   => Result: %s\n" % testOut            
             # capture logging information from test which imports logging and append to wxpython window
```

Comment: The question does not seem to be related to wxpython.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily create a custom logging handler and assign it to the logger used by your module.

See http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html#handler-objects

Comment: I have read the document but not very clear how to get log o/p of another python module

Comment: There is no per-module logging, there is only per-logger logging.  So just fetch the same logger your module is using (`logging.getLogger(...)`) and configure it accordingly.